# VLFeat installation for Python

Tags: python, vlfeat

I am new to Python and I want to install `VLFeat` on Ubuntu (13.04).

I am using Eclipse 3.8. For Python, I have installed the `PyDev` extension on Eclipse.

I have installed Numpy, but I don't know how to install VLFeat. I tried to use their website, but I can't get anything for Python. I have downloaded packages, but I don't know how to install them.

Answer (score 5):

The [Menpo Project](http://www.menpo.org) provides a wrapper around [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/): it's called [cyvlfeat](https://github.com/menpo/cyvlfeat).

> To install cyvlfeat, **we strongly suggest you use conda**:
>
> `conda install -c menlo cyvlfeat`
>
> If you don't want to use conda, your
>   mileage will vary. In particular, you must satisfy the
>   linking/compilation requirements for the package, which include the
>   vlfeat dynamic library.

In other words, the nice thing about installing with `conda` is that it will install (and link) VLFeat dependencies as well.

It may not include all functionalities of VLFeat. [Current State](https://github.com/menpo/cyvlfeat#current-state) as of March 2017:

- fisher

  - fisher
- generic

  - set_simd_enabled, get_simd_enabled, cpu_has_avx, cpu_has_sse3, cpu_has_sse2
  - get_num_cpus,
  - get_max_threads, set_num_threads, get_thread_limit
- hog

  - hog
- kmeans

  - kmeans
  - kmeans_quantize
  - ikmeans, ikmeans_push
  - hikmeans, hikmeans_push
- sift

  - dsift
  - sift

### Relevant reading

[Dev blog](https://gsoc2016.wordpress.com) by [Simmi Mourya](https://github.com/simmimourya1). This includes descriptions and usage examples.

---

### More alternatives:

- [vlfeat-ctypes](https://github.com/dougalsutherland/vlfeat-ctypes): minimal VLFeat interface for python
- [pyvlfeat fork by jchazalon](https://github.com/jchazalon/pyvlfeat): A high-level Python wrapper around a subset of the VLFeat library [more recently updated than the original]

---

#### Note about the IDE

Installing python packages should be independent of the IDE (Eclipse + PyDev, in the OP case), as long as the interpreter and libraries paths are correctly set up.

#### Note about conda

It is not required to install the Anaconda distribution in order to use `conda`. The much lighter [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting [VLFeat from the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvlfeat/), the [instructions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial) are

```
Download distribution, extract it, get to command prompt and type: 
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: I tried it but it started installation and then gave the following error                                                     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1

Comment: user30133479, open setup.py and modify the line LinkArgs = ['-msse', '-shared', '-lboost_python-py26'] to point to your libboost-python version (in my case I had to change it to LinkArgs = ['-msse', '-shared', '-lboost_python-py27'] ).